# How do I move four string 2-dimension arrays as a parameter

Tags: c#-4.0, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

How do I move four string 2-dimension arrays as a parameter?

I have four different 2-dimension arrays (string) I like to send as a parameter to another method and the open the four 2-dimension arrays and read one by one. This time I have four different 2-dimension string arrays; I can sometimes have only one 2-dimension array or maybe ten 2-dimension arrays to send as a parameter, but it will be always a string 2-dimension array.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
            List<string[,]> ListArrayDim2n = new List<string[,]>();
```